# Hide TinyMce Toolbar on init

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce

I want set my tinymce toolbar readonly after my content was set. So I subscribed on the editor on init function like this

```
 editor.on('init', () => {
          editor.setContent(this.value);
          if (this.disabled) {
            editor.contentDocument.body.bgColor = '#eeeeee';
            editor.toolbar = this.disabled ? !this.disabled : undefined;
            editor.setMode('readonly');
          }
```

But if I set the editor toolbar to false the toolbar is always shown. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get toolbar DOM element and hide using css.

```js
var toolbar = editor.getContainer().querySelector('.mce-toolbar-grp');
toolbar.style.display = 'none';
```